# nth neighbourhood of the diagonal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I need the following lemma from commutative algebra for algebraic geometry, and I do not know how to prove it.

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. Let $I$ be the kernel of the ring map $A\otimes_kA\to A$ which sends $a\otimes b$ to $ab$. Let $x^*$ and $y^*$ be two $k$-algebra maps $A\to S$. The induced morphism $A\otimes_kA\to S, a\otimes b\mapsto x^*(a)\, y^*(b)$ kills the ideal $I^{n+1}$ if and only if the following condition holds:

> For each morphism $g^*:S\to T$ of $k$-algebras and elements $t_j\in T$, $a_j\in A$ it holds that $$\left(\sum_jt_j \,g^*(x^* - y^*)(a_j)\right)^{n+1}=0$$

Is it true? I can't even do the case $n=2$.

**Background.** Given an a $k$-algebra $A$, one can define the $n$th neighbourhood of the diagonal $\Delta_{A/k}$. One gets $$Spec (A\otimes_kA/I)\to Spec (A\otimes_kA/I^{n+1})\to Spec (A\otimes_kA)$$
and the sequence of $k$-schemes has a universal property with respect to $n$order thickenings of $k$-schemes. On the other hand, in synthetic differential geometry the $n$th order neighbourhood of the diagonal of an affine space is defined through the following sequent. $$Zar(k)\models
\forall
x,y:Spec A. (x\sim_ny \leftrightarrow \forall f:(\mathbb A_k)^{Spec A}. (f(x)-f(y))^{n+1} = 0)$$
I like to show that the subobjets of $Spec A\times_kSpec A$ are the same (Anders Kock claims that this is the case for affine schemes), and by translating the sequent with help of the forcing semantic I ended up with the algebraic statement above.

**Edit.** To make sure that I didn't do a translation mistake, I will include the process here step by step. I use the forcing semantic which is explained on the [fourth page of this paper](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Ehhalvors/teaching/phi323_f2009/palmgren.pdf).

I like to know under which conditions two generalised points $x,y:Spec\, S\to Spec\, A$ in $Zar(k)$ satisfy that their pair $(x,y):Spec \,S\to Spec \,A\times Spec\, A$ factors through $\sim_n$. According to the forcing sematic (and in the notation of the paper) this is the case if and only if $$Spec \, S \models_{[x:Spec\, A,y:Spec\,A]}\forall
f: (\mathbb A_k)^{Spec\, A}. (f(x) - f(y))^{n+1} =0 \quad[x,y]$$
holds. I am kind of reluctant to introduce to many new names, but the first four occurrences of $x$ and $y$ in the sequent above are just variables in the formal language, while the last two are actual morphisms which are meant to be inserted for $x$ and $y$ later. Next I need to remove the for all quantifier. The sequent above holds if and only if for any map $g:Spec \, T\to Spec \, S$ and $f:Spec\, T\to (\mathbb A_k)^{Spec\, A}$ we have that the following is true.
$$Spec \, T \models_{[x:Spec\, A,y:Spec\,A, f:(\mathbb A_k)^{Spec\, A}]} (f(x) - f(y))^{n+1} =0 \quad[xg,yg, f]$$
Now I need to interpret the terms. The interpretation of $f(x)$ is the composite$$Spec\, T \xrightarrow{(f,xg)} \mathbb A_k^{Spec\,A}\times Spec\, A \xrightarrow{ev}\mathbb A_k$$
Similar for $f(y)$. To turn it into algebra I have to remove the exponential object. Morphisms $f:Spec\, T\to \mathbb A_k^{Spec\, A}$ are in bijection with morphisms $\overline f :Spec \, T\times Spec \,A\to \mathbb A_k$, and under the correspondence the map above becomes $$Spec \, T\xrightarrow{(id,xg)} Spec\, T \times Spec \, A\xrightarrow{\overline f}\mathbb A_k$$. Thus I get the following result, which I like to show.

**Proposition.** Let $I$ again be the ideal of $A\otimes_kA$ which defines the diagonal of $Spec\,A$. Given two morphisms $x,y:Spec \, S\to Spec\, A$ of affine $k$-schemes, I like to show that the pair $(x,y)$ factors through $Spec(A\otimes_kA/I^{n+1})\hookrightarrow Spec (A\otimes_kA) = Spec\, A\times Spec \, A$ if and only if for each maps $g:Spec\, T\to Spec\, S$ and $f: Spec\, T\times Spec A\to \mathbb A_k$ of affine $k$-schemes we have that $$f\circ (id,x g) - f\circ(id,yg):Spec\, T\to \mathbb A_k$$
is zero to the power of $n+1$.

If I translate that fully into algebra, then I end up with the lemma at the beginning of the question.

**Edit, edit.** The first version of the question contained the following lemma (which was unfortunately an incorrect translation) and the accepted answer below is about that lemma.

> **Lemma.** Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra. Let $I$ be the kernel of the ring map $A\otimes_kA\to A$ which sends $a\otimes b$ to $ab$. Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two $k$-algebra maps $A\to S$. Then the induced morphism $A\otimes_kA\to S, a\otimes b\mapsto \phi(a) \psi(b)$ kills the ideal $I^{n+1}$ if and only if it holds that $$(\sum_i a_i\phi(b_i) - a_i\psi(b_i))^{n+1} = 0$$for each element $\sum_i a_i\otimes b_i$ of the ring $A\otimes_kA$.

Comment: Are you sure that’s the correct translation? This condition feels a bit weird… for instance, you haven’t specified an $A$-algebra structure on $S$. Also, considering $(n+1)$-st powers of arbitrary sums is a lot less natural than (and maybe not equivalent to) considering arbitrary products of $n+1$ such elements…

Comment: @Aphelli I will edit the question to include my translation process.

Comment: @Alphelli I did indeed translate incorrectly, thank you for spotting it. I modified the lemma, but now your counterexample doesn't apply no more. I will add the old version at the end.

Comment: Basically your new condition is: for any $S$-algebra $T$, the $(n+1)$-th power of any element in the ideal generated by the image of $\phi-\psi$ vanishes. I think my counterexample still works (because $x \longmapsto x^p$ is still a morphism of algebras).

Comment: @Aphelli Well, SDG texts often secretly assume that all natural numbers are invertible in the base ring, so I guess that makes sense. Thx!

Comment: @Aphelli Hmmm. In "Synthetic Geometry of Manifolds" in remark A.3.3 A. Kock claims that it is true for (at least) all fields $k$ (without assumptions about the characteristic). So either it is a mistake, or I have to talk to a logician who can help me with the translation :/

Comment: I’m not *sure*, but I’d call the result mistaken then. In positive characteristic, there’s a real difference between the ideal generated by the $n$-th powers and the $n$-th power of the ideal (which is essentially what the distinction is about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a definite answer: with a suitable tweak (accounting for the fact that there is no natural $A$-structure on $S$), it should be *yes* in characteristic zero, but it is *false* in positive characteristic. More precisely, if $(n+1)!$ is invertible in $k$, then the statement holds.

---

The counter-example first: let $p$ be a prime number, $S=\mathbb{F}_p[x,y,z]/(x^p,y^p,z^p)$. Note that $S$ is local Artinian and every non-invertible element has nilpotency order at most $p$.
Take $A=\mathbb{F}_p[s,t]$, $\phi: (s,t)\longmapsto (x,y)$, $\psi: (s,t) \longmapsto (y,z)$. The kernel of multiplication $I$ is generated by $s_1=s\otimes 1-1 \otimes s$, $t_1=t\otimes 1-1\otimes t$.

Note that $\phi-\psi$ always takes non-invertible values, so that “your condition” holds.

But $(\phi \otimes \psi)(s_1t_1)=(x-y)(y-z) \neq 0$, so that $\phi \otimes \psi$ doesn’t kill $I^2$.

---

Now for the positive result. First, $I^{n+1}$ is the ideal generated by the products of $(n+1)$ elements of $I$ – we can even say: the products of any $n+1$ elements among a system of generators for $I$. Note that $I$ is generated by the $a\otimes 1-1\otimes a$.

So $\phi \otimes \psi$ kills $I^{n+1}$ iff for every $a_1,\ldots,a_{n+1} \in A$, $\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}{\phi\otimes\psi(a_i\otimes 1-1\otimes a_i)}=0$, ie iff $\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}{(\phi-\psi)(a_i)}=0$.

This obviously implies “your condition”.

Now assume that something slightly stronger than your condition is verified: we have $\left(\sum_i{a_i(\phi-\psi)(b_i)}\right)^{n+1}=0$ for all $a_i \in S$, $b_i \in A\otimes A$ (this is still implied by the fact that $\phi \otimes \psi$ kills $I^{n+1}$).

Let $J$ be the ideal of $S$ generated by the image of $\phi-\psi$. Then $\phi \otimes \psi$ kills $I^{n+1}$ iff $J^{n+1}=0$, but the above condition is equivalent to $z ^{n+1}=0$ for all $z \in J$. We conclude (provided that $(n+1)! \in k^{\times}$) with the following lemma.

*Lemma*: let $I$ be an ideal of a ring $R$ and $n \geq 1$. If $n!$ is invertible in $R$, then $I^n$ is generated by the $i^n$ for $i \in I$.

*Proof*: induction over $n$. The case $n=1$ is trivial. Assume $n\geq 2$ and the statement holds up for integers $k \leq n-1$. Let $J_n$ be the ideal generated by the $n$-th powers of elements of $I$.

Let $u \in I$, let $I’=\{t \in R,\, tu \in J_n\}$, then it is enough to show that $I’$ contains $nx^{n-1}$ for each $x \in I$: since $I’$ is an ideal, the induction hypothesis means it then contains $I^{n-1}$, so $uI^{n-1}$ is contained in $J_n$ for all $u \in I$, so that $I^n \subset J_n$.

Now, let $x \in I$, and let, for every integer $q$, $P(q)=\frac{(x+qu)^n-x^n}{q} \in R$ (with the suitable extension at $0$). Now $P$ satisfies a good linear recurrence relation, $P$ has degree $\leq n-1$, and $P(q) \in J_n$ for $1 \leq q \leq n$), so that $P(0)=nx^{n-1}u \in J_n$, so that $nx^{n-1} \in I’$.

Comment: Ohhh, I am so sorry. I realized that I indeed translated the logical sequent incorrectly. I will accept your answer! Thank you for the work. Maybe your positive result solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out why the algebra did not work out the way I liked it to. The $n$th neighbourhood of an $S$-scheme $X$ should not be defined by testing it against maps $X\to \mathbb A_S$, but by testing it against maps $X\to \mathbb A^r_S$ for arbitrary $r$. What I was looking for is the following statement.

**Proposition.** Let $X$ be an $S$-scheme and let $\Delta_{X/S}^n$ be the $n$-th order infinitesimal thickening of the diagonal $\Delta_{X/S}$. Let $T$ be an arbitrary $S$-scheme, and let $x_0,x_1:T\to X$ be two test maps of $S$-schemes. Then the following are equivalent.

1. The pair $(x_0,x_1)$ lies in $\Delta_{X/S}^n$.
2. The two morphisms $x_0$ and $x_1$ agree on all field valued points, and whenever  $U$ is open in $X$, $r$ is a natural number, and $(f_1,...,f_r):U\to\mathbb A_S^r$ is a morphism, then $(f_1,...,f_r)\circ x_0 - (f_1,...,f_r)\circ x_1$ lies in $D_S(r,n)=Spec \, \mathbb Z[x_1,...,x_r]/(x_1,...,x_r)^{n+1}\times S \subset
   \mathbb A_S^r$.

The corresponding algebra statement is the following lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra (where $k$ is any ring) and let $I$ be the kernel of the multiplication map. Let $x_0,x_1:A\to B$ be two $k$-algebra maps. Then $a_0\otimes a_1\mapsto x_0(a_0)x_1(a_1)$ kills $I^{n+1}$ if and only if $x_0 y = x_1 y$ whenever $y:C\to K$ is a morphism into a field, and $$\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(x_0(a_i)-x_1(a_i))=0$$for arbitrary elements $a_1,...,a_{n+1}$ of $A$.